# Magit remove local branches that were merged into another branch

Tags: magit, git

Explaining the problem more in-depth than the titular definition:

Often I merge branches into master and want to prune based on that. `M-p` works fantastic for removing the remote branches (eg `origin/mergedbranch`) but not the local branch (eg `mergedbranch`) that referenced it before. I'm left with branches like the in the screenshot below.

There seem to be a lot of cli git commands [such as this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143078), but I was wondering if there was a magit equivalent.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The refs buffer has options to filter to merged branches.
Quoting <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(magit)References Buffer`:

> ‘y’ (‘magit-show-refs’)
> This command lists branches and tags in a dedicated buffer.
> However if this command is invoked again from this buffer or if
> it is invoked with a prefix argument, then it acts as a transient
> prefix command

Therefore you can access that transient menu with
<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><sup>1</sup>

Within the transient menu you can refine the view with
<kbd>-</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> setting the value to the merge target
(E.g `develop` or `main`).

Then type <kbd>y</kbd> to execute the command, comparing against
`HEAD`. The refs list you are left with should only contain merged
branches.

Now highlight all the branches you would like to delete, then press
<kbd>k</kbd> to delete the selection.<sup>2</sup>

Remember that you can set and save default transient values with
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>
respectively.

---

<sup>1</sup> or <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `magit-show-refs`,
or in Evil it's <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.

<sup>2</sup> or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `magit-delete-thing`,
or in Evil it's <kbd>x</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such command, but it wouldn't be hard to create one if you know a little emacs lisp and look at other `magit-branch-*` commands and the SO answers you mentioned. If you do, then please submit a pull-request.